# how to set text to split into 2 lines in swift uiTextField

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

I have a uiTextField with dynamic text.

How can I set it via the editor to split the text into 2 lines (or more)

if text doesn't fit in the uiTextField width?

Is there a way to do this not programmatically?

Now text is seen as

`"This is a long line"` ===>

```
"This is...."
```

and I  want it to be

```
"This is a
 long line"
```

Comment: why you are not try the UILabel , label has number of lines property

Answer (score 5):

`UITextField` is one line only. You can not have multi line content in `UITextField`. If you want to have multi line then use `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

As Vishnu said you need to use `UITextview` for multiple row textfield
also add a "\n" where you want to break the string into the next line like so
     `"This is a\nlong line"`